# Help wanted LaTeX keeps giving me error

Tags: errors, xparse

Hi everyone LaTeX keeps giving me the error "missing $ inserted" and "extra }, or forgotten $"

```
\Def{Convergenza uniforme}
{Si dice che $f_n$ converge uniformemente a $f$ se $\displaystyle\forall
\epsilon>0,\exists\bar{n};\forall n\geq\bar{n}\quad\sup_{x\in X}\vert
f_{n}(x)-f(x)\vert<\epsilon$ cioè se $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}
d_{\infty}(f_{n}(x),f(x))=0$ indicheremo con $f_{n}\cu f$}
```

My document heading is:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

With these self defined commands:

```
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Ex}{g}{\textbf{Esempio:}\begin{addmargin}[0.8cm]{0cm}#1\end{addmargin}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Dim}{g}{\textbf{Dim:}\begin{addmargin}[0.8cm]{0cm}#1\end{addmargin}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Def}{gg}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Definizione}} #1:\begin{addmargin}[0.8cm]{0cm}#2\end{addmargin}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Oss}{mg}{\textbf{Osservazione:}\begin{addmargin}[0.8cm]{0cm}#1\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\\ \Dim{#2}}\end{addmargin}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Teo}{gmm}{\textbf{Teorema\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{ #1}:}\begin{addmargin}[0.8cm]{0cm}#2\\ \Dim{#3}\end{addmargin}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Prop}{mg}{\textbf{Proprietà:}\begin{addmargin}[0.8cm]{0cm}#1\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{\\ \Dim{#2}}\end{addmargin}}

\newcommand{\cu}{\stackrel{\mathclap{\tiny\mbox{\Vert\quad\Vert_\infty}}}{\to}}
```

Comment: please don't just post fragments, post a small complete document that makes the error, so people can debug it. Unrelated to teh error but it is almost always wrong to use  `\displaystyle` like this: `$\displaystyle`

Comment: `\mathclap{\tiny` will also generate an error as you can not use size commands in math mode.

Comment: Your error is `\mbox{\Vert\quad\Vert_\infty}`  because the content of `\mbox`  is text so can not have math mode commands unless you nest `\mbox{$\Vert\quad\Vert_\infty$}` but it would be better not to have the box.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Your error is `\mbox{\Vert\quad\Vert_\infty}` because the content of `\mbox` is text so can not have math mode commands unless you nest `\mbox{$\Vert\quad\Vert_\infty$}` but it would be better not to have the box